# PostScript control loop - server loop

Tags: postscript

I'm investigating the start/server loop.
The Insi de Postscript book explains the /start procedure.
One part of that procedure is the control loop:

```
...
{
  //serverdict /server get exec

  //serverdict begin

  setstreams
  setnulldevice
  /execjob
  load

  end
  exec
} loop
...
```

Now i'm trying to find out what /server exactly does and how it might look like (in its most simple form).

```
//serverdict /server get exec
```

This line above gets the server procedure and executes it immediately.

Now I have a server loop like this:

```
/server {
 { % server loop
    (i'm in a server loop) print flush
    (%stdin) run
 }
 loop
} def
```

but i'm stuck in an infinite loop. How and when can the server loop ever go to the next step *(//serverdict begin setstreams etc...)*  as it is currently in an infinite loop?

Comment: Are you trying to understand an existing implementation or create your own implementation? If it's creating your own, what are the constraints? Do you want to run one file at a time in isolation, or a list of files from the command-line, or just user input? Do you want to catch errors?

Comment: Read about `stop` / `stopped` operators in plrm

Comment: trying to understand the workings of an existing one to get my own implementation working. I can just do a C# while-loop and handle all things, no problem but I want to do it like a printer does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the control loop you show, the object bound to the name `server` does not seem to loop the way your code does. It seems to do some initialisation and then return. The expression `/execjob load` seems to run the current job. Outside of all that is a `{ ... } loop` expression which seems to be the server loop which you implemented.

If you want to insert your own server code into the supplied loop, you need to work with the contents of `//serverdict` which your interpreter supplies. If you want to write your own server loop, it seems like you need to go out one level, and replace that entire `{ ... } loop` expression, and maybe `//serverdict` as well.

If you want to "find out what /server exactly does and how it might look like…", how about looking at it? The moral equivalent of:

```
//serverdict /server get == flush
```